# PHP global variable is undefined inside a function even if global keyword is used

Tags: php, variables, global-variables, scope

Yes I know global variables is a bad practice, but ease up on that rule for this one :P

My code:

```
include('something.php'); //where $from is declared

function myfunc() {
    global $from;
    echo "from(myfunc)=$from<br />";
    ...
}

echo "from=$from<br />";
myfunc();
```

The result is:

```
from=2010-05-01
from(myfunc)=
```

What's going on? :(

EDIT:
If it helps, all the code above is inside a view file in CodeIgniter ( and yes, I know functions are not supposed to be inside views :P )

Comment: I tested it and it works fine (after adding a semicolon after the `echo`) on PHP 5.3.1.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'll bet a beer you are not inside the global scope with this snippet. Are you calling this from within a function?

In that case, the `$from` you define in `something.php` is not global, while the one you reference in the function is.

It will probably work if you add a `global $from;` inside `something.php` before you define `$from`.

Needless to say, it's not a nice practice either way, and you should follow Gordon's advice.

Comment: Hi Pekka, you're right. I added `$GLOBALS['from'] = 'value'` outside the function, and the value was found inside `myfunc()`. I didn't realize this page was generated by CodeIgniter's `$this->load->view()` function. Thanks!

Comment: 13 years later ... I've just used IIFE in a legacy code base exactly to isolate globals and it did not even occur to me that I actually needed global scope for globals to work as expected, lol.

Answer (score 17):

Do yourself a favor and use [Dependency Injection.](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection)

```
function myfunc($from) {
    return "from(myfunc)=$from<br />";
}
$from = '2010-05-01';
echo myfunc($from);
```

Doing so will make your code more maintainable, less coupled and more easily unit-testable because it is isolated from the global scope. Plus, when you do it people think you are cool.

Comment: +1 I've never realized I can say "I've being doing dependency injection since 2002" :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll be using Dependency Injection instead :P